# Prove that $[(a|b)\land(c|d)]\Longrightarrow ac|bd;\, a|b\Longrightarrow ac|bc;\, ac|bc\Longrightarrow a|b.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

> Prove that:
>
> $$(a): [(a|b)\land(c|d)]\Longrightarrow ac|bd;$$
>
> $$(b): a|b\Longrightarrow ac|bc;$$
>
> $$(c): ac|bc\Longrightarrow a|b.$$

---

Proof:

(a) By definition of divisibility, there exists two integers $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ such that:
$$a|b\Longrightarrow b = a\cdot n_{1} \,\text{and}\,c|d\Longrightarrow d = c\cdot n_{2}.$$
Multiplying the two statements, we have
$$b\cdot d= (a\cdot n_{1})\cdot(c\cdot n_{2})=ac(n_{1}n_{2}).$$
Let $n'=n_{1}n_{2}$. Since the product of $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ are integers, it follows that $n'$ is an integer. Thus, $$bd=ac(n_{1}n_{2})=ac\cdot n'$$
and by definition of divisibility, $ac|bd$.

(b) $a|b \Longrightarrow b= a\cdot n\,$ for some integer $n$. Multiplying both sides by $c$, we have $bc = ac \cdot n$. Thus, by definition of divisibility, $ac|bc$.

(c) $ac|bc \Longrightarrow bc = ac\cdot n\,$ for some integer $n$. Dividing both sides by $c$, we have $b = a\cdot n$. Thus, by definition of divisibility, $a|b$.

---

Are these proofs sufficient?

I also have some question about (c). Isn't it assumed that $c\neq 0$? Since dividing by $0$ is undefined? Also, after proving $(b)$ and $(c)$, we can simply say $a|b\Longleftrightarrow ac|bc$? Is this correct?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those proofs look good to me. As for (c), yes you have to assume $c\neq 0$ (otherwise the statement is false, for example $2\cdot 0 | 1 \cdot 0$ but $2$ doesn't divide $1$.

You are correct, for $c\neq0$ $a|b \Leftrightarrow ac|bc$.